# Dice Rolling Game

Tags: java, validation, while-loop, character, dice

So in this dice rolling game, what the user inputs must follow the format of xdy, where "x" is the number of dice and "y" is the number of sides the dice has. If the input doesn't follow the format, the program should ask the user to put in another input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input;
    System.out.println("Please enter the number and type of dice to roll in the format <number>d<sides>.");
    input = user_input.nextLine();  

    while()
            {
            System.out.println("Input is not valid. Please enter a new input");
            input = user_input.nextLine();
            }

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(5);
```

My question is, how do I make the `while` loop check for a character between two integers?

Answer (score 1):

One elegant way to do this would be with a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+d\\d+");
input = user_input.nextLine();  

while (!p.matcher(input).matches) {
    System.out.println("Input is not valid. Please enter a new input");
    input = user_input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: What if more than 9 dice, and/or a die with more than 9 sides is desired? Wouldn't `\\d+d\\d+` be a better regular expression for this purpose? Also, why not use the `Pattern` to capture the number of dice and the number of sides of the die?

Comment: @Bobulous good point, thanks! Edited and improved as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Separate numberOfSides and number OfDice into two variables and then do whatever you want with them.

```
String input="6d3";
int numSides=Integer.parseInt(input.split("d")[0]);
int numDice=Integer.parseInt(input.split("d")[1]);
```